# The called method [name] is defined here warning shows without the corresponding deprecation notice

Tags: ruby, deprecation-warning

Usually you get this deprecation notice pair in Ruby 2.7:

warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call

warning: The called method `[method name]' is defined here

But I am seeing the second warning without the corresponding deprecation notice.  Here are two examples of method definition and call where this happens.

```
def method1(x:)
end

method1(x: "x")

def method2(x, y: [])
end

method2("x", y: [1])
method2("x")
```

Note: If I put the above in a standalone ruby file it runs without warnings (I explicitly ran it with the warning flag to make sure).

I could have missed a call somewhere, but assuming I didn't why would I see the helper warning telling me where the method is defined without the corresponding deprecation notice?

Comment: Are you sure you call your methods using `method1(x: "x")` and not `some_variable = {x: "x"}` then `method1(some_variable)` or `method1({x: "x"})` in your actual code?

Comment: You can find the deprecation rules for automatic conversion of keyword arguments and positional arguments [here](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/25/ruby-2-7-0-released/).

Comment: If I pass as a var I get the deprecation notice. My issue is that I am getting the helper warning telling me where the method is defined alone, without a corresponding deprecation notice.  And I have read the deprecation help page which does not help me solve this particular issue.

Comment: So, just to clarify, when you run `ruby -e "def method1(x:); end; method1({x: 'x'})"` you don't get the *"Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated"* warning, but only the *"The called method `method1' is defined here"* warning?